# Why does GitHub Search (API) returns inconsistent content?

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

I am trying to fetch all the merged pull requests with a label. But for one repository and specifically, [one single PR](https://github.com/CodeFlow201/forestTreesTagging/pull/54), the API / Search UI returns inconsistent values.

We all know the we can search in GitHub API in two ways:

1. Using the Global Search. [Search Query returns 1 Result](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Apr+is%3Amerged+label%3Agssoc21+author%3ADOOMSTERR+repo%3ACodeFlow201%2FforestTreesTagging)

   [image]
2. Using the Project Level Search. [Search Query returns 2 Results](https://github.com/CodeFlow201/forestTreesTagging/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Amerged+label%3Agssoc21+author%3ADOOMSTERR)

   [image]

Does anyone know what's the difference and why is it happening this way? Should I change my query or actually, it's the same query with different results.

Should we raise a bug in the GitHub API Issues page? Please can someone tell me why is [this particular Pull Request](https://github.com/CodeFlow201/forestTreesTagging/pull/54) not being counted?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git itself; GitHub's API is not part of Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure, but on observing the PRs, I can see that the 2 PR are there in repo, but only one is accepted as a contribution, the earlier one got reverted, after merge.

[image]

as you can see here: In your first PR that got merged... but later reverted back

[image]

so now this PR won't count, as it now longer belongs to the repo,
so it is not shown in Global Search,

But because it exists in log of PRs, it is still accessible from PR tab.

Because of that, Global Search shows just one PR.

[image]

I hope this explains the ambiguity we have stumbled upon. :)

Comment: Hi thanks, yes, this is one speculation I could see. But is there an evidence in the docs confirming that it's because of this? Anything authentic? This is a great find, thanks. But still, why does the **same query** shows differently?